# Getting strict inequality in $|f(x)|\le \frac 1x$, $x\gt 0$, where $f(x)=\int_x^{x+1} \sin t^2 \, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Given that $f(x)=\int_x^{x+1} \sin t^2 \, dt$

Substituting $u=t^2$ gives:

$f(x)=\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{\sin u}{2\sqrt u}\,du=\frac{\cos x^2}{2x}-\frac{\cos (x+1)^2}{2(x+1)}-\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{\cos u}{4u^{3/2}}\, du$

It follows that $|f(x)|\le\frac 1{2x}+\frac 1{2(x+1)}+\frac 1{2x}-\frac 1{2(x+1)}=\frac 1x$

But how to refute the possibility that $|f(x)|=\frac 1x$ for some $x\gt 0$?

I tried to prove the strict inequality using contradiction as follows:

Suppose on the contrary that there exists a $y\gt 0$ such that $|f(y)|=\frac 1y$, then $|f(y)|=\frac 1y=|\int_y^{y+1}\sin t^2\,dt|\le1\implies y\ge 1$

$y\ne 1$ as $y=1\implies |f(1)|=1=\int_1^2\sin t^2\, dt$, which is not true as RHS is approximately $0.50$. So we must have $y\gt 1$.

Let $g(x)=\frac 1x-f(x)$ and then I try to see if $g$ is monotonic on $(1,\infty)$ or not  but $g'(x)=-\frac 1{x^2}+\sin x^2-\sin(x+1)^2\ge-1+\sin x^2-\sin (x+1)^2$.

I am stuck here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: To indicate how tight this inequality is: The stronger inequality $|f(x)|<1/(x+1/2)$ holds everywhere _except_ in the vicinity of roughly $x=4.33$, with the maximum violation being only about $4\times 10^{-4}$. So the inequality cannot be improved by much. (This almost-bound is obtained by linearizing $\sin(t^2)$ at $t=x+1/2$; the resulting integral, which is a good approximation for most $x$, is readily carried out and does satisfy the above bound.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly derived that
$$
f(x)=\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{\sin u}{2\sqrt u}\,du=\frac{\cos x^2}{2x}-\frac{\cos (x+1)^2}{2(x+1)}-\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{\cos u}{4u^{3/2}}\, du \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
|f(x)| \le\frac{|\cos x^2|}{2x}+\frac{|\cos (x+1)^2|}{2(x+1)}+\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{|\cos u|}{4u^{3/2}}\, du  \\
\overset{(*)}{<} \frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\int_{x^2}^{(x+1)^2}\frac{1}{4u^{3/2}}\, du = \frac 1x \, .
$$
We have a strict inequality at $(*)$ because $|\cos u| = 1$ does not hold for all $u \in [x, x+1]$.

Comment: One can probably also show that $|\cos (x^2)| = 1$ and $\cos(x+1)^2 = 1$ cannot hold simultaneously, but that would be more difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't understand how the final conclusion was reached. I tried to work on that $|\cos x^2|=1$ and $|\cos (x^2+1)|=1$ can't happen simultaneously but couldn't proceed further.

Comment: @Koro: If two continuous functions satisfy $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx \le \int_a^b g(x) dx$, with equality only if  $f(x) =g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that the stronger bound $|f(x)|<\dfrac{1}{2x}+\dfrac{1}{2x+2}$ is also valid. (It holds numerically up to at least $x=12000$, though that's hardly exhaustive.)

Comment: +1. I understood that. So we let $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$ and we have $\int h(x)\, dx=0\implies h=0$ by continuity of $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b]$. Thanks a lot $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I looked up one solution (different than this) and this is what I understood from that:  If $|\cos x^2|=|\cos (x+1)^2|=1$ then $x^2=m\pi, (x+1)^2=n\pi$ where $n\gt m\ge 0$ and eliminating x from those gives us a quadratic equation with rational coefficients whose roots are pi which is a contradiction as pi is transcendental. :)